# How do I pass two meta value to WP_Query

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm having issues with my WP_Query. So I have two select boxes created using ACF one for Country and one for sector. When I select country and leave sector empty I get all the posts with the selected country and like wise for the sector. What I need to do is filter it further so if both are selected and not just one I get all posts from that country and sector. My args  below any help is appreciated.

```
$field_key_country = "field_57b4439b5e371";
$field_country = get_field_object($field_key_country);
$country_sector = isset($_POST['country_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['country_select']) : false;

$sector_key = "field_57e15152d896d";
$sector_field = get_field_object($sector_key);
$sector = isset($_POST['sector_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['sector_select']) : false;

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'distributer_search', 
   'posts_per_page' => -1,
   'meta_query' => array(
       'relation'       => 'OR',
        array(
           'key'        => 'dis_country',
           'value'      => $country_sector,
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'dis_sector',
            'value'     => $sector,
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Are you storing both meta values with the same key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it's helpful for you -

```
$field_key_country = "field_57b4439b5e371";
$field_country = get_field_object($field_key_country);
$country_sector = isset($_POST['country_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['country_select']) : false;

$sector_key = "field_57e15152d896d";
$sector_field = get_field_object($sector_key);
$sector = isset($_POST['sector_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['sector_select']) : false;

$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'distributer_search', 
   'posts_per_page' => -1
);
if($country_sector){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'        => 'dis_country',
        'value'      => $country_sector
    );
}
if($sector){
    $args['meta_query'][] = array(
        'key'       => 'dis_sector',
        'value'     => $sector
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code with relation AND & compare operator.
Also please check WP_Query class at https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```html
<?php
 $country_sector = isset($_POST['country_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['country_select']) : '';
 $sector = isset($_POST['sector_select'])? sanitize_text_field($_POST['sector_select']) : '';
 $args = array(
  'post_type' => 'distributer_search', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'meta_query' => array(
   'relation'       => 'AND',
   array(
    'key'        => 'dis_country',
    'value'      => $country_sector,
    'compare'   => '=',
   ),
   array(
    'key'       => 'dis_sector',
    'value'     => $sector,
    'compare'   => '=',
   )
  )
 );
?>
```

'distributer_search', 
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation'       => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'        => 'dis_country',
                'value'      => $country_sector,
                'compare'       => '=',
            ),
            array(
                'key'       => 'dis_sector',
                'value'     => $sector,
                'compare'       => '=',
            )
        )
    );
?>

Comment: Thanks Nishant this works if both selects are selected is it possible to have an AND and OR say if they only want to search countries and not countries and sector?